# How to measure the memory usage

Tags: delphi

I am coding with Delphi 2009, I want to know how much memory the program used. since the memory manager doesn't releases unused memory back to OS when the object are freed, it might cache in memory manage for next use.  My question is if there is a possible way to known how much memory the program used. It should exclude the memory cached in memory manager. Thanks.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the full version of FastMM contains a demo memory usage tracker program. That sounds like what you need.

Comment: I think there are several questions on this topic already. See for exampel http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448129/why-doesnt-my-programs-memory-usage-return-to-normal-after-i-free-memory or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475592/how-to-convince-the-memory-manager-to-release-unused-memory

Comment: Could somebody comment "Inside - Windows" value in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4448129/why-doesnt-my-programs-memory-usage-return-to-normal-after-i-free-memory question

Comment: Nobody knows what you mean, Branko.

Comment: Ok. In this example - GetMem(P, 1024 * 1024) - FastMem show memory usage 1.048.768 B, GetProcessMemoryInfo() only 4.096 ?

Comment: I thought that using a Windows function to get the memory use was not so useful in that you only get cached values. It's much better to query the Delphi memory manager.

Answer (score 1):

I have a routine that in debug mode calls the FastMM function to get memory use (as David suggested). When FastMM is not installed i.e. in my release mode I use the following code which only needs a reference to Delphi's System unit:

```
function GetAllocatedMemoryBytes_NativeMemoryManager : NativeUInt;
// Get the size of all allocations from the memory manager
var
  MemoryManagerState: TMemoryManagerState;
  SmallBlockState: TSmallBlockTypeState;
  i: Integer;
begin
  GetMemoryManagerState( MemoryManagerState );
  Result := 0;
  for i := low(MemoryManagerState.SmallBlockTypeStates) to
        high(MemoryManagerState.SmallBlockTypeStates) do
    begin
    SmallBlockState := MemoryManagerState.SmallBlockTypeStates[i];
    Inc(Result,
    SmallBlockState.AllocatedBlockCount*SmallBlockState.UseableBlockSize);
    end;

  Inc(Result, MemoryManagerState.TotalAllocatedMediumBlockSize);
  Inc(Result, MemoryManagerState.TotalAllocatedLargeBlockSize);
end;
```

I use XE2 so you might have to change NativeUInt to Int64.

Comment: NativeInt exists on delphi 2009 although I would expect it to be NativeUInt for 32 bit processes that allocate more than 2GB memory.